# Closed Teminal while rails server was running now cannot run again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, terminal

So I am currently learning Ruby on Rails and decided to do their Getting Started guide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I created my test application which in their tutorial is a blog. I didn't have to configure the database because it said if you use the one that's pre made no changed need to be made (SQLite3).

So I created the database using `rake db:create` and then started the server with `rails server` and everything worked perfectly when I went too `http://localhost:3000/` my "Welcome aboard" message was there. Anyways, after I went back to terminal I accidentally did Command + Q which quit Terminal while the server was running. I opened Terminal back up and connected to my blog with `cd blog` then entered `rails server` to hopefully start it up again, but it doesn't work... When ever I go to `http://localhost:3000/` I just get the "cannot connect to server" error. I have even went and deleted the blog folder containing all of the files and then rebooting and creating the blog again but still no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Kill all the rails server processes running and try again

Comment: @Srikanth could you please tell me what the command for this would be? I have tried using the Ctrl + C as they said you can use when it's running but didn't work...

Comment: When you run `rails server` do you get an error message?  If so what?

Comment: look in log/development.log

Comment: If you are using linux and thin server: *ps aux | grep thin* will list all the processes. Kill them.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Activity Monitor, find "ruby" processes and quit them all:

[image: Activity Monitor]

Comment: Just as a note, if clicking "Quit Process" is not working, try Inspect >> Quit >> Force Quit

Comment: In the latest OS X "Quit Process" gives me a modal prompt with buttons "Quit" and "Force Quit". So clicking "Inspect" shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: ah, you are correct, at least when I try that now. For some reason "Quit Process" was not bringing up the modal prompt for me before, but "Inspect" did. I think my computer was under heavy use during the time ... it could be useful information if other people experience the same problem.